# How to set a unique field in a already existing SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question about unique fields in a SQL Server database.

I have a already existing database with an index and some foreign keys and so on.
Now I need to set one column e.g. `name`, to be UNIQUE.

How to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about a unique *constraint*? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Check the 'ALTER Table'-syntax. I don't know how it's in MsSQL, but that sure does the trick for mySQL.

Comment: [How to create a unique index on a table in SQL Server by using SQL Server Management Studio or Transact-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187019.aspx)

Comment: what does altertable do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
ADD CONSTRAINT
    ix_uniquename UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
    (
       name
    ) 
WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

or view the design of the table, right click and select Indexes/Keys

Answer (score 0):

Ff you're talking about adding an index, rather than a constraint then the script is something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_uniquename ON dbo.yourtable([name])
```